# run javascript via url

Tags: javascript

My Problem is:

I have an eibport:
www.bab-tec.de/

You can See a live demo in the live section.

Now the problem.

I would like to start or run a javascript on this page with entering the url like:
  `http:// IP-EIBPORT /#javascript:click(Button)`

or in another way.

Can someone helps me?

Comment: if you did that, anybody could tweak your url to send malicious scripts...

Answer (score 1):

You may want to setup your script to look for a sepcific hash and run a function based on that.

```
switch(location.hash){
   case "#button":
         //click button
   break;
   case "#other":
         //do something else
   break;
}
```

Then use urls like `/#button` or `/#other`

---

The way to do exactly what you want is the following, but it's not recommended!

```
eval(location.hash.substr(1));
```

Use a url like `/#alert('test');` That will work, but it means anyone can link to your site and execute javascript which is a very unsafe thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include JavaScript-invoking code in the URL itself. The best you can do is have a script on the destination page that examines the location, and responds accordingly.

As an example, suppose you wanted to expose `sum` method via the url. If somebody were to load your page with the following query string: `?method=sum&params=5,5`, you could have logic in place to look for these parts, and process them.

```js
var methods = {
    sum: function () {
        var result = 0; i = -1;
        while ( ++i < arguments.length ) 
            result += parseInt( arguments[i], 10 );
        return result;
    }
};

var method = location.search.match(/method=(.*)&/)[1],
    params = location.search.match(/params=(.*)$/)[1].split(",");

var result = methods[ method ].apply( this, params );

alert( result );
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/TF5ta/show/?method=sum&params=5,5